# How to skip the input statement if user not responded to it in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, time

Take this below code as example

```
import time
for i in range(1,10):
    x=int(input("Enter any number: "))
    if x!=None:
         break
    else:
         continue
```

What I need is, if the user didn't respond to the input prompt within 10 seconds, it should go to next statements.

Answer (score 1):

You could spawn a separate thread to take input from the user, and in your main program wait 10 seconds and if nothing is returned kill the thread and set x to none.